# React server side renderer omits setState callback function?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, gatsby

I'm trying to use the second parameter of `setState` to pass a callback function, but it appears (from what I can gather) that the server-side renderer ignores this parameter completely. I'm using [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) which utilizes server-side rendering to build a static React-based site. My call is in an `onChange` handler, and looks like this:

```
this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value }, () => { console.log('setState callback') })
```

The state is updated as expected, but the callback is never called. ***Note***: The same issue applies whether I pass an object or a function for the first parameter. The component function looks like this:

```
ReactComponent.prototype.setState = function (partialState, callback) {
  [...]
  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');
};
```

That updater's method, which lives in `ReactUpdateQueue.js` (*according to the call stack*) looks like this:

```
enqueueSetState: function (publicInstance, partialState)
```

I don't fully understand the build process for React, but I believe that method/file is coming from [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/e932ad68bed656eed5295b61ba74e5d0857902ed/src/renderers/shared/server/ReactPartialRenderer.js) file in the source:

```
/src/renderers/shared/server/ReactPartialRenderer.js
```

The only other place I can find this function defined is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/e932ad68bed656eed5295b61ba74e5d0857902ed/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactNoopUpdateQueue.js):

```
/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactNoopUpdateQueue.js

enqueueSetState: function(
  publicInstance,
  partialState,
  callback,
  callerName,
) {
  warnNoop(publicInstance, 'setState');
}
```

which looks like the correct method signature, but doesn't appear anywhere in the call stack when I debug the `setState` call in my code. This doesn't appear to be a problem with client-side rendered React components (I'll try to set up a simple repo to show this issue, but it doesn't appear replicable on CodePen etc.) I know I could use `componentDidUpdate` to accomplish what I need to do, but the callback is much more convenient in my instance, and I hate leaving a mystery like this unsolved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, and turns out, as is too often the case, this was a self-inflicted error. The default Gatsby install uses React v15 but we wanted to use 16, so we added a direct dependency to it in `package.json`, which got built in to the resulting package. I still don't quite understand why the above mentioned version of `enqueueSetState` was called instead of the proper one, but removing the reference to react (and adding [gatsby-plugin-react-next](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-next), which does what we want by simply pointing webpack to the newer version) fixed the issue.

At least this was a good excuse to get a little more familiar with the guts of React. Perhaps this will save somebody else some time in the future.